# How can I store an element permanetly, even if I restart the program again

Tags: python

```
element = ["Summer","Sun"]
element.append("Ice")
print(element)
```

I want when I restart the program, that "Ice" is still the list.

Comment: You save it to a file, or database, or another persistent item.

Comment: What Willem said. The `pickle` library is pretty standard for this kind of thing.

Comment: If that is all the code thats in your program, then when you run it again, ice will still be in the print output.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: You can't save it in the main memory which is used by the program during its execution and expect it to be present when you're restarting it, for that you have to use another library or file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### As far as I know, there are actually a few options:

1. An external .txt file
2. The module Pickle
3. A database

The module Pickle
- simple example of how to pickle work

```
import pickle
element= ["Summer","Sun"]
element.append("Ice")
pickling_on = open("Element.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(element, pickling_on)
pickling_on.close()
```

So, now that the data has been pickled

```
pickle_off = open("Element.pickle","rb")
element = pickle.load(pickle_off)
print(element)
```